# How can I convert longbits to double in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In Java I can use `Double.longBitsToDouble()` `static` function but in Objective-C I can't find a way to do like that.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really use that method in Java much, but what is wrong with simply setting a long long value to a variable of type double?

A long long will be 64 bits regardless of platform.

You can check for NaN in the double using isnan() in math.h if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy` to copy the bit representation into the address of a variable of type `double`. I'm not sure whether this enters the realm of undefined behaviour.

```
//assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(unsigned long long));

unsigned long long bitPattern = 0x7ff0000000000000ULL;
double doubleValue;

memcpy(&doubleValue, &bitPattern, sizeof doubleValue);

//assert(isinf(doubleValue));
```

The bit pattern for positive infinity was borrowed from [this page](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)) which appears to document the `longBitsToDouble` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint64_t bitPattern = whatever;// use this rather than long long because it is explicitly 64 bits
double  doubleValue;
doubleValue = *(double*)&bitPattern;
```