# How to overcome javascript's 56-bit limitation

Tags: javascript, c, webkit

We are writing a Webkit-based software framework which has a C-backend. We want to pass references from the C layer to the javascript layer at the top. Unfortunately C pointers may be up to 64-bit while javascript only supports up to 56-bit.

How can we overcome this javascript-limitation ?

Our current approach is creating a hashmap in C between our 64-bit pointers and 32-bit integers. The latter are passed on to the Javascript layer.

Comment: The simple solution is to use an array of two numbers in javascript. But design involving communication of pointers between programs are usually bad, so the hash map solution (that is defining some id instead of pointers) might be cleaner.

Comment: In what sense are you talking about "pointers" in JavaScript?

Comment: @nnnnnn: We have C-objects which can be manipulated from javascript through Qt-webkit

Comment: Ah. In that case I would agree with dystroy about using a mapping solution like your current approach rather than trying to do it directly. There are several JS libraries around that implement bigger integers (e.g., http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html), but they're not really applicable to your situation since you wouldn't be doing maths operations on the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply convert the pointers to doubles in the C side (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420972/how-can-i-convert-longbits-to-double-in-objective-c)) , and communicate with JavaScript only doubles. There won't be any loss this way as you'll only deal with IEEE754 double precision numbers whose possible values are the same both side.

But experience shows that exchanging pointers between programs is usually a bad idea (obviously it introduces a strong coupling, for a start), so **I** would use some kind of ID, which is what you do with your hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit pointers on x64 ever [use only the lower 48 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details), in fact spidermonkey and other browsers are relying on this for fast integer/double representation through NaN-boxing.